# how to fill a table with array elements in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have a table in html like this:

```
<table id="someTable">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <span></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <span></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <span></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i have an array someArray with three values in it. I want to iterate through the array and set each array items to a span on each row.

i tried a jquery code like this

```
$('#someTable tr').each(function(i) {
      $(this + 'td:first span').html(someArray[i]);
});
```

the problem is it is setting the last value on the array to all the span's how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). Appending a selector to `this` will not work:

```
$('#someTable tr').each(function(i) {
      $(this).find('td:first span').html(someArray[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find()`:

```
$('#someTable tr').each(function(i) {
  $(this).find('td:first span').html(someArray[i]);
});
```

Or `context` selector:

```
$('#someTable tr').each(function(i) {
  $('td:first span', $(this)).html(someArray[i]);
});
```

Comment: To elaborate: `$(this + 'td:first span')` will return the same results as `$('td:first span')`, thus 3 all 3 spans, and all 3 spans would be filled with content for the last element. This is because this is an object, and not a string, and thus will not be included in the jQuery selector.